# How can I know the size of BigQuery response

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table which stores BigQuery JobIds.
In this table I only have the jobId and **not** the results .
I need to find out the size of the results and I was trying to use [This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) (query-plan-explanation)
However, I don't see the result size in the response only the total bytes scanned

```
"totalBytesBilled": "10485760",
"totalBytesProcessed": "2464625",
"totalPartitionsProcessed": "0",
"totalSlotMs": "127"
```

Any idea how I can get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how I can get this information? (size of query output)

**Step 1** - using jobs.get API (by knowing) `jobid` you extract `configuration.query.destinationTable` (projectId, datasetId, tableId)

**Step 2** - using tables.get API (by knowing projectId, datasetId, tableId) you extract `numBytes` which is the size of this table in bytes, excluding any data in the streaming buffer. Also `numRows`will give you the number of rows of data in this table(still excluding any data in the streaming buffer) .

Comment: This solution assume I have a destination Table? Will it work if I do 1 after 24 hours from the original query execution time? (I'm asking given sometimes I only have temporary table as the destination Table)

Comment: no. it does not assume you have explicit destination table (in case if you do not have explicit table result is saved in so called anonymous table). and it will not work after 24 hours as result will expire by that time.

Comment: I'll have to check if I can always run this before table expire. Tnk.

Comment: sure. it is proven as I am using it for years :o)